# Why are the vertical deflection coils in a CRT deflection yoke so different from the horizontal coils?

Tags: coil, flyback, crt, electric-field

Looking at a typical raster CRT deflection yoke, there appear to be two very different pairs of coils. There is the pair on the inside that curves outwards, and the pair on the outside, which are wound around a ferrite core.

[image: A photograph of a CRT deflection yoke]

The inside coil is the horizontal deflection  coil, which seems to make sense. The coil's field lines go vertically through the tube and deflect the electrons horizontally.

I haven't been able to find information on why the vertical deflection coils are so different. The center axis of the coils seems to go through the ferrite core, not the tube, and it's not obvious why this produces the magnetic field needed to deflect the electrons vertically.

Also, why would there not simply be two pairs of the same design as the horizontal deflection coil? It's plausible that some deflection yokes were designed that way, as shown in this old book (Television Simplified, Kiver, 1973):

[image: A logical diagram of the arrangement of deflection coils around the CRT neck, along with a diagram of the physical placement.]

But I have not been able to find any photos of a yoke with this design, so I assume there's some engineering advantage to the design in the photograph.

Comment: The vertical deflection operates at 50 or 60 Hz, while the horizontal is 505/2 or 525/2 or 625/2 times that. Therefore you don't want excessive inductance in the horizontal deflection coils in order to be able to deflect (and restore) quickly enough.

Answer (score 9):

The vertical coils are driven similarly to a speaker, with a 60Hz (assuming North America) sawtooth.

The horizontal coils operate at a much higher frequency (about 15kHz in N. America) so they cannot easily be driven the same way. They are driven by applying a constant voltage across them, which causes the current to increase linearly di/dt \$\alpha\$ V, and when the electron beam reaches the right-hand side of the screen the beam is turned off and the energy stored in the inductance of the coils is released as the (now imaginary) beam "flies back" to the left hand side of the screen. This is the origin of the "flyback" converter that is ubiquitous in low power off-line switching supplies.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes they are!  See pictures for example here: https://www.aussiearcade.com/topic/78275-move-deflection-yoke-on-sony-trinitron/

Sony Trinitrons (and other licensees) I think often used this design, particularly when high scan rates were demanded.  Trinitron TVs may've used wound ferrites still.

Not that it's easy to see what's going on under there, but you can at least see the ferrite shield is just that -- a shield, not also wound.  Taking one apart, one finds the vertical and horizontal windings have very similar designs.

Monitors typically used a purpose-made amplifier for vertical drive, which, you could probably abuse as an audio amplifier really, but the trick is, it can generate a high voltage in one direction (flyback pulse), for fast retrace, as is of course needed to generate a raster screen.

It might also be more accurate.  Wires can probably be placed more accurately, than ferrite can be molded and wound.

Probably, the wound ferrite design is more popular for TVs, as less accuracy is required, and the fixed frequency (50 or 60Hz, give or take a small margin) is easier to optimize for.  This design will give somewhat higher inductance and Q factor, easing that process.

Note that, in both cases, the ferrite ring/shield serves as a back-side pole piece for anything inside it, so there is definite advantage to the horizontal sweep, to use the ferrite at all.  In the TV design, it serves double duty as vertical deflection AND horizontal shield; in the monitor design, just shield.

By the way, in case you're wondering, the windings are phased opposing: the inductance increase is NOT equal to the core's permeability, but rather modest (2-4x?).  This pushes magnetic field outside the core -- exactly where it's needed to deflect the beam, of course.  With the winding wrapped around the core, this will include exterior fields -- which could cause interference in the TV, so shields, boards, etc. should be kept away.  In monitors, the non-wound shield helps keep fields down, and boards can be placed much closer -- helpful considering the sheer amount of electronics these things needed!