# What is this flange with wire windings in a conical / horn shape?

Tags: identification, winding

I found this thing in a heap of stuff to be dismantled for recycling. There is a flanged chassis with winding wire rising up the wall, going along the rim, and diving back down, all this duplicated on the other half of the circumference. There is also a second layer of winding below that seems to wrap under itself at the rim without following the circumference.

Was it some kind of motor, or perhaps a piston loudspeaker?

[image]

Comment: I'm old ! :-) . It's interesting to see questions like this, when pieces of equipment  from the dawn of time surface :-). This is so familiar to 'old guys like me' that it's easy to forget that they will be almost unknown in new equipment now. || For a zillion images of these, each with a linked web page,  see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=deflection+yoke&sca_esv=596736736&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwiE4fqFqc-DAxVkR2cHHXOeDB0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=3072&bih=1508&dpr=1.25)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a deflection yoke, here is a picture of a similar tube yoke in this question:
[image]
From: [Why are the vertical deflection coils in a CRT deflection yoke so different from the horizontal coils?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/628701/why-are-the-vertical-deflection-coils-in-a-crt-deflection-yoke-so-different-from)

Answer (score 41):

It looks like the [deflection yoke from a cathode ray television tube.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_yoke)  The deflection yoke steers the electron beam to draw the picture on the front of the CRT.

This picture from the Wikipedia page shows what it would have looked like on the TV tube:

[image]